# Why V8-Options don't get entertained properly?

Tags: node.js, v8

I am starting my Nodejs application with following command :

```
node  --max_executable_size=100 --max_old_space_size=100 --max-semi-space-size=2 main.js
```

But still memory pile up beyond 100 MB. Can anyone help me understanding why flags are not entertained properly. Or internally memory expansion happens which allow process to go beyond 100 MB for certain limit.

Answer (score 0):

How much beyond 100 MB?

These are V8 options, but Node.js has its own overhead on top of V8, pushing it beyond 100MB.

Comment: 100 MB was just an example..actual size I provided is 800 MB still it crosses 1 GB..max I observe is 1.41GB.